# Highchart : highlights specific data series

Tags: highcharts

I need to change the border color of a specific data series based on his category in a bar chart ... is it possible with some formatter function?

If yes, are there some examples?? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For setting colors for series you can define an array of [colors](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors).

I'm not sure what you mean with specific data series but it's an option to set color and [border](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.data.borderColor) for each point individually.

```
data: [{
  y: 814,
  borderColor: '#FFFF00',
  borderWidth: 10
}]
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u6czsqmr/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.

I have found a solution that works well.

```
            const scelte = array('uno','due','tre');

                labels: {
                    formatter: function(){
                        var color = (this.value);
                        var sper = scelte.includes(color) ? 'red' : 'blu';
                        return '<span style=\"color: '+sper+';font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;font-family:calibri\">'+this.value+'</span>';

                    }
                }
              },
```

If var color is in array scelte then the label color will be red, in all the other cases the label color will be blu.

I'm trying to solve the same problem for pie chart ... but at the moment I don't find it. Any suggestion?
Thank you